# What do I need to Mod a Unreal Engine 3 game?

Tags: modding, unreal

what I am looking for is some advise making a mod for a certain game and how I would go about making it. The game I am talking about is Blacklight: Retribution and what I wan't to know is;
Is it possible? And if so, what programs will I need?
It is an online only game so I was unsure how plausible a mod would be for it. Plus I have never made a video game before, but I do like the game and I wanted to do some things with it. Additionally, this will be my first time making anything video game related so I would appreciate any advise.

To expand a bit, I plan to add something simple at first. A mod that would let you spectate another player in the first person. Then I plan do something a bit more complex where I want to make so the game optionally always records you playing (in short intervals most likely or you would run quickly out of memory).
After all that is done I would add items, armor, weapons, and maybe make a map or not I am not sure but this in a shell what I hope to do. I don't know much about these things but I am reading anything I can get my hands on. So if this is overly ambitious or just plain out not a possibility any advise on what I should look to instead will be welcomed warmly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to be the one to say it, but modding for that game is not possible. BUT NEVER FEAR! There are tons of games out there to start getting your hands dirty. Seeing as your beginner and never worked with programming I would not recommend something as complicated as recording thing you just described. Surprisingly, the things you mentioned later are actually easier stuff to do. But still complicated for a beginner.

Here are some awesome websites I've found to be very handy over the years.
http://www.pixelprospector.com/

http://unity3d.com/ (A very great engine for the beginner)

Comment: I see, thank you very much. That is rather disappointing but I will just do something else as you suggested. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: NP, and don't be afraid ask any questions if you've got them. :)